# How to allow save without all inputs filled in sign up form cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am having this issue: I want to allow persons to sign up based on 3 different roles: #artiste, manager, fan . When you select the 'artiste' role from the dropdown you get a popup that contains the remaining fields.

If a fan or manager is registering however you will not get the remaining inputs. The problem I am having is that when these additional inputs and image are not added the form will not save.. I want to know why this is happening, all the fields that are optional are set as NULL in the database.

here is my form code:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('class'=>'form-horizontal', 'type'=>'file'));?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('username', array('placeholder'=>'Username', 'div'=>'form-group', 'label'=>false, 'class'=>'form-control'));
    echo $this->Form->input('email', array('placeholder'=>'Email', 'div'=>'form-group', 'label'=>false, 'class'=>'form-control'));
    echo $this->Form->input('first_name', array('placeholder'=>'First Name', 'div'=>'form-group', 'label'=>false, 'class'=>'form-control'));
    echo $this->Form->input('last_name', array('placeholder'=>'Last Name', 'div'=>'form-group', 'label'=>false, 'class'=>'form-control'));
    echo $this->Form->input('middle_name', array('placeholder'=>'Middle Name', 'div'=>'form-group', 'label'=>false, 'class'=>'form-control'));
    echo $this->Form->input('phone', array('placeholder'=>'Your Phone Number', 'div'=>'form-group', 'label'=>false, 'class'=>'form-control'));      
    echo $this->Form->input('password', array('placeholder'=>'Password', 'div'=>'form-group', 'label'=>false, 'class'=>'form-control'));
    echo $this->Form->input('password_confirm', array( 'maxLength' => 255, 'title' => 'Confirm password', 'type'=>'password', 'placeholder'=>'Confirm Password', 'div'=>'form-group', 'label'=>false, 'class'=>'form-control'));
    //new code
    echo '<div class="brandDiv" id="artiste">';
    echo '<div class="artiste-child">';
    echo '<div class="form-group">';
    echo $this->Form->textarea('summary', array('placeholder'=>'Describe yourself, your history in the music business and more', 'div'=>'form-group', 'label'=>false, 'class'=>'form-control textarea2', 'empty' => true));
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="form-group">';        
    echo $this->Form->textarea('role_model', array('placeholder'=>'Your role model in life, start this as: My role model is...', 'div'=>'form-group', 'label'=>false, 'class'=>'form-control textarea2', 'empty' => true));
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="form-group">';
    echo $this->Form->textarea('fav_song', array('placeholder'=>'Your favourite song, start this as: My favourite song is...', 'div'=>'form-group', 'label'=>false, 'class'=>'form-control textarea2', 'empty' => true));
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="form-group">';
    echo $this->Form->input('trailer', array('placeholder'=>'Put the last 11 letters and digits of your youtube video url here', 'div'=>'form-group', 'label'=>false, 'class'=>'form-control', 'empty' => true));
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="form-group">';
    echo $this->Form->input('pdf_path', array('type' => 'file','label' => 'Add a profile image', 'empty' => true));
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="form-group">';
    echo $this->Form->input('genre_id', array('options' => $genres,'class'=>'form-control', 'div'=>'form-group', 'label'=>false, 'empty' => true));
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';      
      //end of new code
    echo $this->Html->div('info', 'Are you a music manager, artiste or just a fan? Choose your role');
    echo $this->Form->input('role', array(
         'options' => array('manager' => 'Manager', '#artiste' => 'Artiste', 'fan' => 'Fan'),'placeholder'=>'Confirm Password', 'div'=>'form-group', 'label'=>false, 'class'=>'form-control'));


echo $this->Form->submit('Sign Up', array('class' => 'form-submit btn btn-default',  'title' => 'Click here to add the user') ); ?>
         <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

This is my user model:

```
<?php
   App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
   App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');


   class User extends AppModel {

//public $hasOne = array('Product');

    public $hasMany = array('Children'=>array(
    'className'=>'User',
    'foreignKey'=>'parent_id'
    ),


    'Image'=>array(
    'className'=>'Image',
    ),

    'Like'=>array(
    'className'=>'Like',
    ),


    'Comment'=>array(
    'className'=>'Comment',
    ),

    'Customize'=>array(
    'className'=>'Customize',
    ));


        public $belongsTo = array(
         'Parent'=>array(
         'className'=>'User',
         'foreignKey'=>'parent_id'
         ),

        'Genre'=> array(
        'className'=>'Genre'
        )

        );

public $avatarUploadDir = 'img/avatars';

public $validate = array(

    'genre_id' => array(
        'nonEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'required'=> false,
            'message' => 'genre is required',
            'allowEmpty' => true
        )),

    'summary' => array(
        'nonEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'required'=> false,
            'message' => 'summary is required',
            'allowEmpty' => true
        )),

    'pdf_path' => array(
        'nonEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'required'=> false,
            'message' => 'image is required',
            'allowEmpty' => true
        )),

    'trailer' => array(
        'nonEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'required'=> false,
            'message' => 'trailer is required',
            'allowEmpty' => true
        )),

    'fav_song' => array(
        'nonEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'required'=> false,
            'message' => 'favourite song is required',
            'allowEmpty' => true
        )),

    'role_model' => array(
        'nonEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'required'=> false,
            'message' => 'role model is required',
            'allowEmpty' => true
        )),

    'username' => array(
        'nonEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'A username is required',
            'allowEmpty' => false
        ),
        'between' => array( 
            'rule' => array('between', 5, 15), 
            'required' => true, 
            'message' => 'Usernames must be between 5 to 15 characters'
        ),
         'unique' => array(
            'rule'    => array('isUniqueUsername'),
            'message' => 'This username is already in use'
        ),
        'alphaNumericDashUnderscore' => array(
            'rule'    => array('alphaNumericDashUnderscore'),
            'message' => 'Username can only be letters, numbers and underscores'
        ),
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'A password is required'
        ),
        'min_length' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', '6'),  
            'message' => 'Password must have a mimimum of 6 characters'
        )
    ),

    'password_confirm' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Please confirm your password'
        ),
         'equaltofield' => array(
            'rule' => array('equaltofield','password'),
            'message' => 'Both passwords must match.'
        )
    ),

    'email' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('email', true),    
            'message' => 'Please provide a valid email address.'    
        ),
         'unique' => array(
            'rule'    => array('isUniqueEmail'),
            'message' => 'This email is already in use',
        ),
        'between' => array( 
            'rule' => array('between', 6, 60), 
            'message' => 'Usernames must be between 6 to 60 characters'
        )
    ),
    'role' => array(
        'valid' => array(
            'rule' => array('inList', array('manager', '#artiste', 'fan')),
            'message' => 'Please enter a valid role',
            'allowEmpty' => false
        )
    ),


    'password_update' => array(
        'min_length' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', '6'),   
            'message' => 'Password must have a mimimum of 6 characters',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'required' => false
        )
    ),
    'password_confirm_update' => array(
         'equaltofield' => array(
            'rule' => array('equaltofield','password_update'),
            'message' => 'Both passwords must match.',
            'required' => false,
        )
    ),

    'current_password' => array(
        'notempty' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty', 'message' => 'please enter your old password'),
        'check password' => array('rule' => 'checkPassword',
            'message' => 'your password is not correct')
    )


);


   public function addArtiste($postData = null) {
if (!empty($postData)) {

    $postData['User']['parent_id'] = CakeSession::read("Auth.User.id");

    $this->create();
    if ($this->save($postData)) {

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
        }
    }
  }

  public function checkPassword($data) {
    $user1=new User();
    $user=$user1->read(null,  $this->data['User']['id']);
    $current_password=AuthComponent::password($data['current_password']);
    if($current_password==$user['User']['password']){
    return true;

    }
}
```

finally this is my UsersController add action  :

```
    public function add() {

//new code
   $genres = $this->User->Genre->find('list', array(
'fields' => array('Genre.name')
));
  $this->set('genres', $genres);

  //end new code
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

                $filename = '';
        if ($this->request->is('post')) { // checks for the post values
    $uploadData = $this->data['User']['pdf_path'];
            if ( $uploadData['size'] == 0 || $uploadData['error'] !== 0) { // checks for the errors and size of the uploaded file
                return false;
            }
            $filename = basename($uploadData['name']); // gets the base name of the uploaded file
            $uploadFolder = WWW_ROOT. 'files';  // path where the uploaded file has to be saved
            $filename = time() .'_'. $filename; // adding time stamp for the uploaded image for uniqueness
            $uploadPath =  $uploadFolder . DS . $filename;
            if( !file_exists($uploadFolder) ){
                mkdir($uploadFolder); // creates folder if  not found
            }
            if (!move_uploaded_file($uploadData['tmp_name'], $uploadPath)) {
                return false;
            }
        $this->request->data['User']['image'] = $filename; 
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Congrats! You have registered'));
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                if ($this->Auth->user('role')=='manager') {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Welcome Manager, '. $this->Auth->user('username')));
                    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'manager'));
                }


                if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                    if ($this->Auth->user('role')=='#artiste') {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Welcome! '));
                        $this->redirect(array( 'controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'artiste'));
                    }

                    if ($this->Auth->user('role')=='master') {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Welcome admin, '. $this->Auth->user('username')));
                        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
                    }


                    else {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Welcome, '. $this->Auth->user('username')));
                        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'favourites'));
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password'));
                }
            } 
            //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('You could not register, please try again'));
        }   
    }
}

    $genre_list = $this->User->Genre->find('all');

    $this->set('genre_list', $genre_list);
```

}

Comment: Is it throwing any kind of error message?

Comment: I got a validation error on the genre and image upload, however using "'allowEmpty' => true" does not work

Comment: You have a conflict in your validation code. These two can not be together 'rule' => array('notEmpty') and 'allowEmpty' => true.

Comment: Fixed that, same issue